# Copying a Azure Blob and injecting in azure media services gives System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceQueryException

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

for Ingesting assets to Media Services from another blob storage account, Followed the steps
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/MediaServices/thread/9bcaf96d-3a47-4e76-8c95-3bd9200ba432 
My code is :

```
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = Microsoft.WindowsAzure.CloudStorageAccount.Parse(RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue("AzureStorageString"));
private static readonly string _accountName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["accountName"];
private static readonly string _accountKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["accountKey"];
```

---

```
    public ActionResult UploadData(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
    {
        CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        CloudBlobContainer blobContainer = blobClient.GetContainerReference("rawvideos");
        if (blobContainer.CreateIfNotExist())
        {
            blobContainer.SetPermissions(new BlobContainerPermissions
            {
                PublicAccess = BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Blob
            });
        }

        CloudMediaContext _context = new CloudMediaContext(_accountName, _accountKey);
        Guid g = Guid.NewGuid();
        IAsset assetToBeProcessed = _context.Assets.CreateEmptyAsset("YourAsset_" + g.ToString(), AssetCreationOptions.None);
        IAccessPolicy writePolicy = _context.AccessPolicies.Create("Policy For Copying", TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30), AccessPermissions.Write | AccessPermissions.List);
        ILocator destinationLocator = _context.Locators.CreateSasLocator(assetToBeProcessed, writePolicy, DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-5));
        CloudBlobContainer sourceContainer = blobContainer;
        CloudBlobContainer destinationContainer= blobClient.GetContainerReference("rawvideocopy");
        if (destinationContainer.CreateIfNotExist())
        {
            blobContainer.SetPermissions(new BlobContainerPermissions
            {
                PublicAccess = BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Blob
            });
        }


        foreach (var file in files)
        {

          CloudBlockBlob rawVideoFileRef= blobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(file.FileName);
          rawVideoFileRef.UploadFromStream(file.InputStream);


         CloudBlob sourceFileBlob = sourceContainer.GetBlobReference(file.FileName);
         sourceFileBlob.FetchAttributes();
         long sourceLength = sourceFileBlob.Properties.Length;
         CloudBlob destinationFileBlob= destinationContainer.GetBlobReference(file.FileName);
         destinationFileBlob.CopyFromBlob(sourceFileBlob);
         destinationFileBlob.FetchAttributes();
         long destLength = destinationFileBlob.Properties.Length;
         assetToBeProcessed.Publish(); 
         assetToBeProcessed = RefreshAsset(_context,assetToBeProcessed);
        }


        return View();
        }
```

---

assetToBeProcessed.Publish(); 
 gives an error :

```
 System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceQueryException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2146233079
  Message=An error occurred while processing this request.
  Source=Microsoft.Data.Services.Client
InnerException: System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceClientException
       HResult=-2146233079
       Message=<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?><error xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata"><code>Internal Server Error</code><message xml:lang="en-US">Asset has no files uploaded.</message><innererror><message>Asset has no files uploaded.</message><type>System.ArgumentException</type><stacktrace>   at Microsoft.Cloud.Media.Vod.Rest.Data.Repository.AssetRepository.InitMainFile(IDataStore dataStore, AssetRecord asset) in d:\Builds\100\IISMediaServices\Release_Official\Sources\Nimbus\Release\src\Vod\Rest\Data\Repository\AssetRepository.cs:line 346&#xD;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the URL for the destinationFileBlob from your destinationLocator.